# dotnet core accessing specific path in a container outside of WORKDIR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, containers

In my container I have a file in the following path:

```
/mnt/secrets/ACCESS-KEY
```

`ACCESS-KEY` is a file with one line of string in it that is required by the dot net core application in order for it to be run.

In the `appsettings.json` file of the application I have:

```
  "Credentials": {
    "ACCESS_KEY_Path": "/mnt/secrets/ACCESS-KEY",
  }
```

in my .CS file I am trying to read the file by doing :

```
  var accessKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Credentials:ACCESS_KEY_Path")))
```

**However,** in the container logs I can see it throws an error by saying:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> **> path '/app/mnt/secrets/ACCESS-KEY'**

For some reason, dot net append the "**/app/**" to the begining of the path I have configured. I guess the reason is because in the `Dockerfile` the `WORKDIR` is set to `/app`, and now I am wondering how can I access a file outside of this `/app` directory but within the same container?

Comment: What are you trying to achive by calling `Path.GetFullPath` at right path to your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check when you should use `Path.GetFullPath`? There are [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1). You can use it when you need to get full path to specified file/folder.
Note, why it adds `/app`:

> Important
> If path is a relative path, this overload returns a fully qualified path that can be based on the current drive and current directory. The current drive and current directory can change at any time as an application executes. As a result, the path returned by this overload cannot be determined in advance. To return a deterministic path, call the GetFullPath(String, String) overload. You can also call the IsPathFullyQualified method to determine whether a path is fully qualified or relative and therefore whether a call to GetFullPath is necessary.

To solve your problem don't use it.

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Credentials:ACCESS_KEY_Path"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As `/mnt/secrets/ACCESS-KEY` starts with a `/`, it's an absolute path from the root so this should be sufficient:

```
var accessKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Credentials:ACCESS_KEY_Path"))
```